# left merge is changing the index of the dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

dataframe old_2:

```
  some_column key_column
0   old_val_0  changed_0
1   old_val_1  changed_1
4   old_val_2  changed_2
```

dataframe compare_old_df:

```
  some_column   key_column audit_column_1 audit_column_2
0   old_val_0    changed_0            foo            bar
1   old_val_1    changed_1            foo            bar
2  same_val_0  unchanged_0            foo            bar
3  same_val_1  unchanged_1            foo            bar
4   old_val_2    changed_2            foo            bar
5  same_val_2  unchanged_2            foo            bar
```

I am trying to merge these two dataframes (left merge) and I want to keep the index of old_2 dataframe.

I have tried this:

```
old_changed=old_2.merge(compare_old_df, how='left')
```

```
  some_column key_column audit_column_1 audit_column_2
0   old_val_0  changed_0            foo            bar
1   old_val_1  changed_1            foo            bar
2   old_val_2  changed_2            foo            bar
```

The index has changed. I want to have the index like old_2 dataframe

Comment: Please don't overwrite the question, I fixed the formatting. If you really want to modify something, do it from one of my clean versions!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is changing the index, as even for a left merge there can be several matches.

A trick to avoid this issue is to temporarily set the index as columns with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then restore it:

```
old_changed = (old_2.reset_index()
               .merge(compare_old_df, how='left')
               .set_index('index').rename_axis(old_2.index.name)
              )
```

Output:

```
  some_column key_column audit_column_1 audit_column_2
0   old_val_0  changed_0            foo            bar
1   old_val_1  changed_1            foo            bar
4   old_val_2  changed_2            foo            bar
```